# How to fetch records with aggregation in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using below range aggregation in ElasticSearch and I want the aggregated records also with doc count. Can it be achieved ??

Below is the query:

```
    {
   "aggs" : {
       "Age" :  {
            "filter" : { "range" : { "AGE" : { "gt" : 33 } } }
        }  
    }
}
```

and here is the output:

```
  {
    "aggregations" : {
    "Age" : {
      "doc_count" : 2
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to fetch the records also ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , you can use the [top hits aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)

The documents in that bucket would be returned.
The below code should work fine -

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "Age": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "AGE": {
            "gt": 33
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "results": {
            "top_hits": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```